# How to use @ ('at' char) in comments when username contains whitespace

Tags: discussion, comments

When posting a comment with the intent to ping another user, but including mention of `@<username>` in the comment text, what should I do if the username contains whitespace, e.g. 'exampleFirst exampleLast'?

I suppose that writing `@exampleFirst exampleLast` will ping the user named 'exampleFirst', whereas I wish to ping the user named 'exampleFirst exampleLast'.

Comment: Just type the name without spaces.

Comment: Full reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comment box lets you type <kbd>@</kbd> and then some letters, and it will show you who can be pinged. Just click on their name, and it will insert it for you.

If you feel like doing it manually for some reason, do it without the spaces.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't find it reliably showing me any username after '@'. For instance, no names appeared when I typed '@' at the start of this comment. (I since deleted the '@'.) Anyway, "without the spaces" is just the answer I needed.

Comment: @JellicleCat It only shows up once people have already commented. Try replying to this one.

Comment: Alas! No luck! I did get 'AndrewMedico' to appear when I responded to his comment above, though.

Comment: @JellicleCat the user who posted the question or answer you comment on is always notified, so you can't ping them explicitly.